# Why is a function re-definition faster than calling the first one?

Tags: php, javascript, performance, v8

I am reading javascript files in php and execute them using v8js.

Simplified example:

```
$javascriptCode = file_get_contents($filename);
$funcName = 'func'.md5($filename);
$v8js->executeString("
 function {$funcName} () {
  {$javascriptCode}
 }");
$v8js->executeString("var testVariable = {$funcName}();");
```

**~50 calls = 200ms**

To improve performance I reduced subsequent calls to only calling the function name if the function was already defined:

```
if ( !isset($this->cache[$filename]) ) {
 $javascriptCode = file_get_contents($filename);
 $funcName = 'func'.md5($filename);
 $v8js->executeString("
  function {$funcName} () {
   {$javascriptCode}
  }");
  $this->cache[$filename] = $funcName;
}
else {
 $funcName = $this->cache[$filename];
}
$v8js->executeString("var testVariable = {$funcName}();");
```

**~50 calls = 900ms**

For some reasons this is slower than re-running the function definition (first code part).

I have several dozen of javascript files and functions I am calling, all which ran within 200ms using the first code example. After adding a caching for already defined function names and no longer re-defining them, the runtime for the exact same code was about 900ms.

To verify that the missing re-definition is the only reason for the performance loss I changed the if:

```
if ( !isset($this->cache[$filename]) || true ) {
```

… having the function name still been saved to the array, excluding the php-array as a possible problem.

Where does the big performance loss come from or how can I debug this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created several tests to identify everything further and finally found the reason hidden deep inside my own javascript code.

Even that the code was identical, some `if` in the javascript decided to sideways and made everything slower :-)

Here is the source code to the last test I did which has shown that without the re-definition it is faster like it was expected:

```
<?php
$runList = array(10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000);
$jsFunc = 'function myTestFunc () { return {foo: "bar"}; } ';
foreach ($runList as $runs ) {

    $start = mstime();
    $js = new V8Js('Test');
    for ( $i = $runs; $i > 0; $i-- ) {
        $js->executeString($jsFunc, 'Test.Context');
        $js->executeString("myTestFunc();", 'Test.Context');
    }
    echo "#1: " . (mstime() - $start)." ({$runs} with re-definition)<br />";
    unset($js);

    $start = mstime();
    $js = new V8Js('Test');
    $js->executeString($jsFunc, 'Test.Context');
    for ( $i = $runs; $i > 0; $i-- ) {
        $js->executeString("myTestFunc();", 'Test.Context');
    }
    echo "#2: " . (mstime() - $start)." ({$runs} without re-definition)<br />";
    unset($js);
    echo "<hr />";
}

function mstime() {
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}
```

Results:

```
#1: 0.000640869140625 (10 with re-definition)
#2: 0.0003800392150878906 (10 without re-definition)
#1: 0.001749992370605469 (100 with re-definition)
#2: 0.0009560585021972656 (100 without re-definition)
#1: 0.01554703712463379 (1000 with re-definition)
#2: 0.04881501197814941 (1000 without re-definition)
#1: 0.503957986831665 (10000 with re-definition)
#2: 0.1761679649353027 (10000 without re-definition)
#1: 4.813416957855225 (100000 with re-definition)
#2: 1.93553900718689 (100000 without re-definition)
```